# Python installing OPCUA package

Tags: python, pip, package, opc, opc-ua

Hey guys i have this problem:

I have to install OPCUA package for python. I have already installed opcua with
pip install opcua. But I have this problem:

In my Python code:
from opcua import Client,ua

i get this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytry.py", line 1, in 
    from opcua import Client,ua
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opcua'

i tried to do this in the cmd and i thought i have to install crypthography so i wrote the command: pip install cryptography

But then i get this message:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Mikail\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1su9k_x\cffi\

Can anyone help me? I am new in Python and OPCUA

Note: i have a windows 10 OS

Comment: Hi...Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install opcua correctly.

Try to use `pip list` to check is it installed.

You can get examples from https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua, and go to examples folder.

```
$ python server-minimal.py
```

Open another terminal

```
$ python client-minimal.py

Objects node is:  Node(TwoByteNodeId(i=84))
Children of root are:  [Node(NumericNodeId(i=85)), Node(NumericNodeId(i=86)), 
Node(NumericNodeId(i=87))]
myvar is:  Node(NumericNodeId(ns=2;i=2))
myobj is:  Node(NumericNodeId(ns=2;i=1))
```

crypthography is just for security, it's not necessary to install.

If crypthography is not installed, you will get a message,

```
cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to module being not installed properly or the installed Python package is an older version.
Check if the opcua module is installed using

```
pip list
```

If the problem persists, then try updating the Python package (Python version > 3.4), else try using pip3 instead of pip.

Since the python-opcua library is in maintenance mode, you can try out the examples available in opcua-asyncio which is the fork of python-opcua: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/tree/master/examples

You can refer to the documentation available here: https://opcua-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You can also try out these open source OPC UA implementations that you might find interesting:

- open62541 – https://open62541.org/certified-sdk.html – C stack |
  Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready
- NodeOPCUA – https://node-opcua.github.io/ – NodeJS | MIT License |
  Cloud ready
- UA .NET stack – https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard –
  RCL License for corporate members of OPC Foundation & GPL 2.0 for
  others | Standard profile | Web oriented implementation

If you are looking for more hands-on information (it uses another open source stack) , you can also check out these resources:

- Free documentation: You can look at the open source documentation
  page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- Paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code
  walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack:
  https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i

Answer (score 3):

Start Windows cmd and enter the command:

```
py -m pip install opcua
```